# Is there a way to simplify repeated use of generics in static methods in JAVA?

Tags: java, function, generics, static

I created a `final` class with multiple static methods. The generics used in all of those methods are same, any suggestion how this can be simplified any further?

```
public final class SomeUtils {
    public static <REQUEST extends RequestClass, RESPONSE> ReturnClassA<REQUEST, RESPONSE> funcA() {
        ...
    }

    public static <REQUEST extends RequestClass, RESPONSE> ReturnClassB<REQUEST, RESPONSE> funcB() {
        ...
    }

    public static <REQUEST extends RequestClass, RESPONSE> ReturnClassC<REQUEST, RESPONSE> funcC() {
        ...
    }

}
```

P.S: I am using JDK8. I cannot upgrade that for sometime.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what makes you say there's no way to implement them? Try it with `Map` instead of `ReturnClassA` and `return new HashMap<>();` as the body.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate making these instance methods of a class with type parameters, rather than static methods, then you can avoid the repetition:

```
public final class SomeUtils<REQUEST extends RequestClass, RESPONSE> {
    public ReturnClassA<REQUEST, RESPONSE> funcA() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // fill in with whatever implementation you need
    }

    public ReturnClassB<REQUEST, RESPONSE> funcB() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // fill in with whatever implementation you need
    }

    public ReturnClassC<REQUEST, RESPONSE> funcC() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // fill in with whatever implementation you need
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
ReturnClassA<RequestClass, Object> a = new SomeUtils<>().funcA();
```